# Is it possible to write a wrapper class which will take function name as an argument and applies it on a dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I would like to write a wrapper class in pyspark which will take function name as an argument. same wrapper class will be used to apply different functions on a pyspark dataframe. For example, If i wish to apply Filter & Fillna functions, i will be doing as follows:

WrapperClass.transform(df1, Filter, filter_condition)

WrapperClass.transform(df1, Fillna, fillna_condition)

is it possible? If yes, can you please share an example?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: if you don't mind, can you please share an example?

Comment: Can someone please share an example?

Comment: Do you have an example to share? appreciate your help.